# Comparing Columns and Highlight the Matching Data Using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I Need to compare `Column B` in `Sheet 2` with `Column C` in `Sheet 3` and highlight the cells with matching data in `Column B (Sheet 2)`.

Have used the following formula in *Conditional Formatting*

which works `=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Sheet3!C,Sheet2!B,1,FALSE)))` with Format type being a

particular color say Yellow `Interior.colorindex = 6`

How to implement the same using code in VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
Sub CompareAndHighlight()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i)
        For j = 1 To Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C" & j)
            If StrComp(Trim(rng1.Text), Trim(rng2.Text), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                rng1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            End If
            Set rng2 = Nothing
        Next j
        Set rng1 = Nothing
    Next i

End Sub
```

the code checks all cells in Sheet2 column B against each cell from Sheet3 column C and if they match it highlights cells on Sheet2 in Column B in yellow

Comment: The Code works well. I had not put forth my question more clearly. The above code compares for example b2 in sheet 2 with c2 in sheet 3 and so on. I would like the each value in Sheet 3 to be checked against all the values in the other column. For which another loop would be required. Can you please edit the code to add the above mentioned specification and error handling for blank cells?

Comment: I have edited the code for you so it iterates over all cells in Column C on Sheet3. What do you mean with error handling for blank cells?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("sheet2!b:b")
    If c.Value <> "" And Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(c.Row, 3).Value = c.Value Then
        c.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next
```