# Match values in excel and highlight

Tags: vba, excel

Updated explanation:

I work with large lists of data containing debits and credits. Some debits and credits need to be matched and highlighted (in order to get them cleared from the list).

I would like a macro to help me with this task i.e. to begin at the start and work down on a line by line basis (I need to be able to manually review the listing to ensure it is correct thus from the necessity to work from start to finish). Taking cell N1 as an example:
•   If N1 is yellow, do nothing
•   If N1 has no colour formatting, sum N1 + N2. If N1  N2 = 0, highlight in yellow. 
•   If N1 + N2 does not equal zero, do nothing and move on.
•   If N2 is yellow, do nothing
•   If N2 has no colour formatting, sum N2 + N3. If N2 + N3 = 0, highlight in yellow.
•   And so on. 
•   I would also like this macro to stop when the data set is complete as all empty rows will = zero. Not really sure how that would work?

I have prepared a very simple example (attached) which has three tabs: 
1.  Sample data set
2.  Data set where I have populated absolute values, sorted from smallest to largest
3.  The desired end result. As you can see, there are several instances where there is no offsetting item and the macro would need to skip.

Thanks again for your help! [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdzsm.jpg)

Comment: Could you show, what you already tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing Columns and Highlight the Matching Data Using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464708/comparing-columns-and-highlight-the-matching-data-using-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will do pretty much what you are expecting, it will go from Row 1 to Last on Column N and check whether the sum of two rows is equals 0 and whether they are already highlighted in yellow or not and then it will format the cell as yellow if true:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column N

For i = 1 To LastRow Step 2 'loop through Column N and calculate Sum every two rows
    If ws.Cells(i, "N").Value + ws.Cells(i + 1, "N").Value = 0 And ws.Cells(i, "N").Interior.Color <> vbYellow And ws.Cells(i + 1, "N").Interior.Color <> vbYellow Then
        ws.Cells(i, "N").Interior.Color = vbYellow
        ws.Cells(i + 1, "N").Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to match any two numbers regardless of their position in the list, but only once per set across a single column - i.e. full reconciliation, you will need something like this:

```
Sub test()
    clr = vbYellow
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lastrow - 1
            For j = i + 1 To lastrow
                If .Cells(i, 14).Value = -1 * .Cells(j, 14).Value And .Cells(i, 14).Interior.Color <> clr And .Cells(j, 14).Interior.Color <> clr Then
                    .Cells(i, 14).Interior.Color = clr
                    .Cells(j, 14).Interior.Color = clr
                    Exit For 'include this if the list is long to speed things up
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```